# Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -raft

Tags: go-ethereum

When I run the following command
PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup geth --datadir node1 --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 31337 --raft --raftport 50001 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22001 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --emitcheckpoints --port 21001 >> node1.log 2>&1 &
An error has occurred
Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -raft
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M8kK.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're picking up a standard geth executable instead of a GoQuorum executable.
Run geth version and check what is printed. You should see something like the below:

```js
Geth
Version: 1.10.1-stable
Git Commit: 460df5758e6da0ddb27d3e6d5d492747e7ebad1e
Git Commit Date: 20220622
Quorum Version: 22.4.1
Architecture: amd64
Network Id: 1337
Go Version: go1.16.6
Operating System: darwin
```

The important line is Quorum Version. If you don't see that then you have the wrong executable.